# Converting short? to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm trying to subtract `short? Days` from `DateTime? InitialDate` to get `DateTime FinalDate`.

I'm not sure if, because they are nullable objects, this is causing problems with the comparison. I've tried casting `days` to a `TimeSpan` without success.

```
short? Days = 7;
DateTime? InitialDate = new DateTime(2012, 10, 5);

DateTime FinalDate = InitialDate - Days ;
//FinalDate should be 5/3/2012 12:00 AM
```

FinalDate should be `5/3/2012 12:00 AM.`

Comment: DateTime has the "AddDays()" and similar functions. To substract, just "add a negative". Also maybe in this case, you should verify that no input is a null value at the start of the function and throw a "ArgumentException" if someone gave you a null. That would be better then having to deal with this all the way through.

Comment: What do you want to do in case either the `Days` or `InitialDate` variables are `null`? Why are they nullable / how do you want to handle them?

Comment: I'm working with a database, and, for some reason, whoever created it made the values nullable. It's a pain! There are rarely cases where these values are null. I think the answer for this question handles it, so I'll stick with `AddDays()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the variables you are dealing with are nullable types, you have to make use of the `.Value` property of them to access its value. You can also make use of the `.HasValue` property to check whether it is having any value.

Now comes the subtraction part, I'm not sure what is the role of TimeSpan that you mentioned in the question. But from the output specified and the name of the variable, I assumed that its the number of days. If my understandings are correct, then you can try the following code to subtract the `Days` from `InitialDate` to get the `FinalDate`

For a safe side, you can check whether the `InitialDate` has a value or not before accessing them.

```
DateTime? FinalDate = InitialDate.HasValue ? InitialDate.Value.AddDays(-(Days.HasValue? Days.Value : 0)) : null;
```

[This Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xT3I97) may help you to understand things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract the `Days` value from the `InitialDate` using the `AddDays` method, passing in the negative value of `Days`. Since you don't show what you want to happen it either value is `null` I've made `FinalDate` nullable:

```
short? Days = 7;
DateTime? InitialDate = 5/10/2012 12:00 AM;

DateTime FinalDate? = null;
if(Days.HasValue && InitialDate.HasValue)
{
  FinalDate = InitialDate.Value.AddDays(-Days.Value)
}
```